# ngb-pagination with an async collection not working

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have the following table with pagination:

```html
<ng-container mCardBody>
  <fieldset class="form-group position-relative mb-0">
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-xl input-xl" id="iconLeft1"
      placeholder="Search Users" [formControl]="searchCtrl">
    <div class="form-control-position">
      <i class="feather ft-search font-medium-4"></i>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Lastname</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center">Admin</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers | async  | slice: (page-1) * pageSize : page * pageSize; index as i">
      <th scope="row">{{ user.id }}</th>
      <td>{{ user.name }} </td>
      <td>{{ user.lastname }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <i *ngIf="user.admin" style="color: green;" class="ficon feather ft-check"></i>
        <i *ngIf="!user.admin" style="color: red;"  class="ficon feather ft-x"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block text-center">
          <button class="btn btn-info" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Action</button>
          <div ngbDropdownMenu class="arrow _dropdown_mob dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
            <button class="dropdown-item" (click)="editUser(user)">Edit</button>
            <button class="dropdown-item" (click)="deleteUser(user)">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center pagination-separate ">
    <ngb-pagination [(page)]="page"
    [pageSize]="pageSize"
    [collectionSize]="filteredUsers.length" aria-label="Default pagination"></ngb-pagination>
  </ul>
</nav>
</ng-container>
```

this is the `ts` file:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../_services/data.service'
import { NgBlockUI, BlockUI } from 'ng-block-ui'
import { AlertService } from '../../_services/alert.service'
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormControlDirective, FormControlName, FormGroup, AbstractControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { take, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  @BlockUI('changelog') blockUIChangelog: NgBlockUI;

  users = [];
  public breadcrumb: any;
  options = {
    close: false,
    expand: true,
    minimize: true,
    reload: true
  };

  pageSize = 5;

  page = 1;

  public searchCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();
  private _onDestroy = new Subject<void>();
  public filteredUsers:  ReplaySubject<any[]> = new ReplaySubject<any[]>(1);

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    private alertService: AlertService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.breadcrumb = {
      'mainlabel': 'Users Administration',
      'links': [
        {
          'name': 'Home',
          'isLink': true,
          'link': '/dashboard/sales'
        },
        {
          'name': 'Admin Users',
          'isLink': false,
          'link': '#'
        },
      ]
    };
    console.log('OnInit users component');
    this.getUsers();
    this.searchCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy))
            .subscribe(() => {
              this.search();
            });

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._onDestroy.next();
    this._onDestroy.complete();
  }

  search(){
    console.log("Search invoked");
    let search = this.searchCtrl.value;
    console.log("Search term is:",search);
    if (!search) {
      console.log("Search is empty");
      console.log("Filtered media is:",this.filteredUsers);
      this.filteredUsers.next(this.users.slice());
      return;
    } else {
      console.log("Filtered media is:",this.filteredUsers);
      console.log("Search is:",search);
      search = search.toLowerCase();
    }

    this.filteredUsers.next(
      this.users.filter(user => (
        user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1 ||
        user.lastname.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1
        )
      )
    );
  }

  getUsers() {
    this.dataService.getUsers().subscribe({
      next: (users) => {
        console.log('Received users:', users);
        this.users = users;
        this.filteredUsers.next(this.users);
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.log('Received error downloading users:', error);
      }
    })

  }

  editUser(user) {
    console.log("Received user to edit:", user);
  }

  deleteUser(user) {
    if (window.confirm('Sei sicuro di voler cancellare l\'utente?')) {
      console.log("Received user to delete:", user);
      var id = user.id;
      this.blockUIChangelog.start('Loading..');
      this.dataService.deleteUser(id)
        .subscribe({
          next: (response) => {
            this.deleteRow(id);
            this.alertService.success("User successfully deleted");
            this.blockUIChangelog.stop();

          },
          error: (error) => {
            this.alertService.error("An error occured");
            this.blockUIChangelog.stop();
          }
        });

    }
  }

  reloadChangelog() {
    this.blockUIChangelog.start('Loading..');
    this.getUsers();

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.blockUIChangelog.stop();
    }, 2500);
  }

  deleteRow(id) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.users.length; ++i) {
      if (this.users[i].id === id) {
        this.users.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  onUserCreated(user: any) {
    console.log('OnUserCreated emitted:', user);
  }

}
```

The pagination is not showing any page because the `filteredUsers` is not a collection and can't detect the size. How do I indicate the collection size in this case? Considering that it can change depending on the search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply `| async` pipe to get length as below:

```
[collectionSize]="(filteredUsers | async)?.length"
```

[Sample solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-18zsa8)

Comment: I tried your solution - but getting error like - `Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'`. how to resolve this?

Comment: Think what you need is to provide a default value when the variable is `undefined`. Example: "YourNumber || 0". If you still have the issue, would suggest creating a new question by providing Minimal Reproducible Example. Thanks.

Comment: I used it like this and it is resolved:`[collectionSize]="(foodItems | async)?.length??0"`